# Finding modifier in a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence, clauses, modifiers

Given sentence: **Although she didn't have much work experience, she was offered the job.**

Question: find the modifier. What type of modifier?

Here we have a dependent clause and an independent clause. The sentence is connected by 'although'. Can we say that the dependent clause is the modifier?

That is, she didn't have much work experience, can be classified as an essential modifier..

Answer (score 1):

*Although she didn't have much work experience* is a concessive adjunct.

Adjuncts are modifiers in clause structure - as compared with the predicator (verb) and its complements (subject, object, predicative complement, licensed prepositional phrases etc.).

It is similar to:

> Although inexperienced, she was offered the job.

The entire constituent headed by  *Although* is an adjunct, no matter whether it contains a subordinate clause or not.